# sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc/update-manager/sed2l1b5x: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sed

When I launch a Ubuntu terminal I have this error : `sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc/update-manager/sed2l1b5x: Permission denied`.
The file `sed2l1b5x` is random each time I launch the terminal.

All the answers I found seem not correspond with my problem. How can I fix that?

Comment: look into `~/.bashrc` file ... what do you see?

Comment: I have not modified `~/.bashrc`. What should I see? However, I have created `~/.bash_aliases` and `~/.bash_profile`. I finally deleted the `~/.bash_profile`. It was useless. Everything seemed to work fine.

Comment: `sed` seems to be loaded whenever you open your terminal ... This has to come from a line/s in those files you mentioned or other files included in them ... The terminal reads and executes them every time you open it ... look for lines with `sed` in them and comment them out by prepending `#` to them then test with closing and reopening your terminal to see if its not showing that message anymore.

Comment: In the files I have created there is not `sed` mentionned. I deleted them and checked. Nothing change.  Using `grep "sed" .bashrc` : `alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'` Nothing seems the cause.

Comment: Please post the output of `grep -P 'sed|update-manager' ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment`.  If that doesn't show us where this is coming from, then you will be sourcing some other file, so we will need to see the output of `grep -P '(\.|source) ' ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment`

Comment: That alias contains command substitution which should happen as soon as you open the terminal ... Not sure about those quotes couldn't trace them :-) but possible

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the output of the above commands : [link](https://i.imgur.com/Ni6aX6E.png)

Comment: For what it is worth, `history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\''` looks weird in my eyes, `history | tail -n 1` - reads out the last command in the history, but then; the -e commands for sed seems broken, unless someone actually may explain what it is supposed to do with that single history line. My guess is that the qoutes are severely messed up.

Comment: My question to OP is: Have you solved this annoyance?

Comment: @modlin No I didnt. I installed again my Ubuntu distribution.

Comment: Affected too...

Answer (score 2):

I finally get rid of the message by changing the commandline parameter of the used profile in Terminal to

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wsl.exe -d <profile>
```

e.g.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu
```

### Investigation

Based on @Eduardos answer I tried to figure out when during startup this file gets triggered by inserting `echo` commands into the files that gets invoked by the bash. The sed access error came even before `/etc/profile` gets executed.

The file `/etc/wsl.conf` did not contain any relevant changes.

After comparing the wsl profile in Terminal with a default one I recognized my profile used `Ubuntu.exe` as Command line argument while the default one had `C:\WINDOWS\system32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu`

Comment: I can confirm that this does rid us of the annoyance.

Answer (score 1):

After rg the root system I found this file:

```
/var/lib/dpgk/info/ubuntu-release-upgrader-core.preinst
```

which has the following line:

```
if dpkg --compare-versions "$2" lt 1:0.189 && [ -f /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades ]; then
            sed -i -s 's/^prompt=/Prompt=/' /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
fi
```

Running the sed part I can confirm that this file is being run every time I open a new terminal as I also started to have this problem today. Still not sure what triggered the problem and how to solve it,though.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to J_D's answer, here is a screenshot of where to change the command line argument.

- It resides in Terminal settings (little down array, right beside opening a new tab).
- Select the Ubuntu profile, in the left navigation panel.
- Second entry on the page is command line. Paste `C:\WINDOWS\system32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu` into it.

Terminal settings, Ubuntu profile:

[image: Screenshot of Terminal settings. Ubuntu profile.]

Answer (score -1):

This popped up on my ubuntu wsl. what i did in desperation is to give 777 at two directories...

```
/etc/update-manager/
/var/log/
```

after this and a restart the nagging message is gone.. not sure if giving 777 to these two directiores is bad... but since is a local development ubuntu... meh